# Most performant way to introduce styling rules to a document for in an embedded script?

Tags: javascript, css, performance, dom, stylesheet

I'm creating an embedded third party Javascript, and it needs to inject some styled markup onto the page.  The easiest way that I know how to add styling rules to the DOM (as opposed to simply styling individual elements) is by doing:

```
var l = document.createElement('link');
l.rel = 'stylesheet';
l.media = 'screen';
l.href = 'http://server/stylesheet.css';
document.body.appendChild(l);
```

I know that there's a document.styleSheets API, but it seems fairly complicated, and I'm not sure if it's worth the performance gains at this point in my project's game for me to learn it.  What I'm trying to avoid is the additional HTTP GET to fetch `http://server/stylesheet.css`.  So unless I'm making the DOM stylsheets API to be some sort of ferocious bully that it isn't, are there any other ways of doing this that avoid the extra network hit?

What about just having:

```
var iH = '' +
         '.sel.ect + or {' +
             'property: rule;' +
         '}';
var s = document.createElement('style');
    s.innerHTML = iH;
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

Are there any caveats aside from unmaintainability of CSS to doing it this way?  I suppose it would add some extra bloat to my JS file in a somewhat purpose-defeating manner, though I could just minify my CSS with Vim and make it one long incomphrehensible string literal without concatenation.

What does SO have to say about this?  Or should I just suck it up and learn the stylesheets API?

Comment: I prefer your second method for the same reason you're asking this question. Is there a reason you aren't using the javascript style property?

Comment: Should that be appended to the head?

Comment: It really doesn't matter whether it gets appended to `head` or `body`.  I've actually found [this](https://github.com/jugglinmike/DressUp) more recently, which you may find useful for implementing my idea.  If not, I've refashioned it for myself with a few more features into this larger build script right [here](http://dpaste.org/yTcQU/).  I'm quite happy with how it turned out for my own needs, and I think it's a better way than what DressUp does... Feel free to PM me up on freenode, if you have any questions on how to use it. (my nick's adlwalrus)

Comment: Thanks adlwalrus. I've been looking for something good to use for this purpose. There's the css.php way which is kinda ok, but options are nice. I'm not too familiar with node(in the sense that I'm never used it, and only read about it), but I might give it a try someday. The minification would be nice.

Comment: Don't worry!! It's just javascript. That's what's so awesome about it. Believe it or not, what you see in that paste was literally my very first (and yet only) node script... that's how easy it is. Also, you don't need to "know" node to use my script... it's just a program that you need node installed to run. And installing node couldn't be easier.

Comment: Start by installing node from nodejs.org and then go from there.